# C++ destructor weird behavoiur

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a model class which contains the buffers for the model to draw, it's implementation looks like this:

```
Model::Model(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<short> indices)
{
    mVertices = vertices;
    mIndices = indices;
    mMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    mIsTextured = false;
    Initialize();
}

Model::~Model()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mVertexBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mIndiceBuffer);
}

void Model::Initialize()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &mVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*mVertices.size(), &mVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mIndiceBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndiceBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(short)*mIndices.size(), &mIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Now I've encountered a very weird problem with the destructor, I use this class like this:

```
Renderer *renderer = new Renderer();
Model m = parseSKNFromFile("model.skn");
m.ApplyTexture(textureID);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    update();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    renderer->RenderModel(&m);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Using the Model class this way triggers a runtime Access Violation Reading Location error, but if I comment the glDeleteBuffers call inside the constructor everything working find.
It looks like somehow those delete functions called out of nowhere and I cant figure out how and why.

Here's the RenderModel function too:

```
mShader.bind();

glm::mat4 MVP = mProjection * glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 100, 200), glm::vec3(0, 100, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)) * model->GetMatrix();
glUniformMatrix4fv(mShader.getUniformLocation("MVP") , 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

if (model->IsTextured())
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model->GetTexture());
    glUniform1i(model->GetTexture(), 0);
}

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model->GetVertexBuffer());

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);  //float position[3]
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)12);    //char boneIndex[4]
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)16); //float weights[4]
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)32); //float normals[3]
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)44); //float textureCords[2]

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model->GetIndiceBuffer());

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model->GetIndiceSize(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
```

Comment: Do not forget the rule of three: Do you have a copy ctor and copy assignment operator?

Comment: This line is very likely the source of your problem: `Model m = parseSKNFromFile("model.skn");`. If you write `parseSKNFromFile (...)` to return a pointer to an object allocated on the heap instead of making a copy, a lot of headaches will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

An assumption: You do not have (can not have) a proper copy constructor/assignment operator.

Hence:

```
private;
Model(const Model&); // No copy
Model& operator = (const Model&); // No copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating an inline object of Model it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope and that scope is at the end of the function where you instantiate a Renderer.

I would suggest changing the Model to a heap allocated object and destroy it manually before you free the Renderer and before you destroy the window.

```
Model* m = parseSKNFromFile( "model.skn" );
```

There are some other suggestions that I would make like taking the arrays of indices and vertices as const references in the constructor of the Model. Also I don't think it is a great idea to call gl commands from the destructor of the object, it would be better to separate that type of functionality to separate functions in the Model as well as not initialize the OpenGL buffers in the constructor either. The reasons for that is in case you want to separate object allocation from the renderer initialization so that you can be loading them on a separate thread from the rendering thread.

Comment: As you can see in the second code I gave, the allocation of the object is in the same function where the object is being used (in this case the main() function), and it still doesn't make any sense becasue everything is working fine if I comment out those commands from the destructor. On another note, if you have any resources for programming OOP with OpenGL please provie them here :D